# How to correct public_path() in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I want to save multiples pictures in database using Laravel.I got an error in public_path() saying

> (message: "Class 'Gallerie_img_client' not found")

here is my code :

```
 public static function uploadImage(Request $request, $user)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {

            $current_timestamp = Carbon::now()->timestamp; // Produces something like 1552296328
            $emitter = User::where('id', $user)->where('active', true)->first();
            $haseFile = $request->input('hasFile');
            $idClient = $request->input('idClient');
            if ($haseFile) {
                foreach ($request->input('files') as $key => $file) {
                    $aa = explode(';', $file['file']);
                    $aa1 = explode('/', $aa[0]);
                    $extension = $aa1[1];
                    $fileName = $current_timestamp . $key . '.' . $extension;
                    if (strpos($file['file'], ',') !== false) {
                        @list($encode, $file['file']) = explode(',', $file['file']);
                    }
                    Gallerie_img_client::insert([
//                        'id'=> '1',
                        'name'=>$file['name'],
                        'url'=>$fileName,
                        'size'=>$file['size'],
                        'idClient'=>$idClient,
                    ]);

                    /*** Save file in folder public/data/Images ***/
              \Gallerie_img_client::put(public_path() . '/data' . '/' . '/Images' . '/' . == >causing me error 

$fileName, base64_decode($file['file']));
                    // Storage::put($fileName, $file);
                }
            }
```

Comment: problem is with your class Gallerie_img_client you are using try to import it

Comment: i did it ofc! but it dosnt work in this line" \Gallerie_img_client::put(public_path() . '/data' ..."

Comment: did you tried importing it like this: use path/to/Gallerie_img_client; ?

Comment: try to remove the slash in the begging of the line

Comment: @HananAlhasan I got this error (undefined method App\Gallerie_img_client::put())

Comment: @Behzad yes it is "use App\Gallerie_img_client;"

Comment: its saying you don't have put method in that class or its not static

Comment: @behazad I didn't understand you ! can you please explain more ! I am using \Gallerie_img_client::put to create a folder under public to save my images

Comment: replace the line you have with this to store your file: $request->file('file')->move('/data/Images',$fileName);

Comment: @HananAlhasan got this error : Call to a member function move() on null

Comment: use $file['file'] or just $file instead of $request->file('file')

Answer (score 1):

You have to you the Storage class to save the file in public_path() or storage_path()

```
Storage::disk('public')->put($filePath, (string) $image, 'public');
```

In the **config/filesystens.php** you'll see code like below which is used in disk function of Storage class. You can create you own if you want.

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Using **Storage disk public** method the files will be stored in `storage/app/public` folder

You have to create a shortcut link in public folder for storage. You can run this `php artisan storage:link` to create link.